# Auto Py To Exe gives error when opening file

Tags: python, pyqt5, exe, auto-py-to-exe

I have a simple python application. I converted it to an exe with Auto-Py-To-Exe and when I opened it, it showed an error which Is shown in here:

[image]

The error says it cannot find the module PyQt5. Can anyone tell me how to import it for auto py to exe?

Comment: the DLL required for this operation failed, you can just search it in google the dll number it says and install it and run it again easy job.

Comment: The dll it wants is pyqt5 widgets which is a part of the pyqt5 dll which is already in it so I'm not sure which dll is missing.